# How to save R plot_ly plots, containing LaTeX, as HTML files

Tags: r, latex, plotly, mathjax

I want to use LaTeX to parse descriptions in my R plot_ly plots. I used the example from plot_ly website, including the latex2exp library and its TeX function:

```
p <- plot_ly(
    x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
    y = c(1, 4, 9, 16),
    name = TeX("\\alpha_{1c} = 352 \\pm 11 \\text{ km s}^{-1}")) %>%
  add_trace(
    x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
    y = c(0.5, 2, 4.5, 8),
    name = TeX("\\beta_{1c} = 25 \\pm 11 \\text{ km s}^{-1}")) %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(
      title = TeX("\\sqrt{(n_\\text{c}(t|{T_\\text{early}}))}")),
    yaxis = list(
      title = TeX("d, r \\text{ (solar radius)}"))) %>%
  config(mathjax = 'cdn')

widget <- widgetframe::frameableWidget(p)
widgetframe::saveWidgetframe(widget, paste0("p", ".html"), selfcontained = TRUE)
```

Problem is that both "p" and "widget" display correctly in R Studio viewer, but I can't get it to save it to a file. I did some research and found that in general, SVG rendering is difficult to combine with HTML:
https://plotly-r.com/mathjax.html

I explored htmlwidget and widgetframe library, but failed to achieve what I wanted.

I don't mind whether the file is large. I'd also like to be able to generate dynamic LaTeX labels in a Shiny app with downloadable plots. Is exporting such plots to HTML doable at all?

Comment: The html file resulting from your code looks fine to me. However, as an alternative you can try `htmlwidgets::saveWidget(p, paste0("p", ".html"), selfcontained = TRUE)`.

Comment: does your plot in html file contain LaTeX labels, exactly as in here:
https://plot.ly/r/LaTeX/

or the labels are just text in monospace font?

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/NBzH7A5) is what I get after opening the standalone html file generated with your code.

Comment: crap, this is exactly what I need. Maybe the issue is, as often in R, package version? Which libraries do you use and in which version?

Comment: R version 3.6.1, widgetframe 0.3.1 and plotly 4.9.1 (latest CRAN versions) - html file displayed via chrome.

Answer (score 0):

So, the files are generated exactly as they should. The issue was... web browser. I've tried viewing the files in Firefox, which displayed LaTeX code in monospace font instead of actual labels. Probably some overzealous security feature working without any indication. Files are displayed correctly in both Internet Explorer and Chrome